# Adding table column with foreign key constraint using migrations in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to add a user_id column with a foreign key contraint to a Todo-table in Node Express using Sequelize with Postgresql.
I get an error message saying "Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "UserId" does not exist". As you can see there is both "userId" and "UserId" in the SELECT query.
[image: "Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "UserId" does not exist"]

The SELECT query is built by a simple Todo.findAll().
I believe it's something wrong in how I create the foreign key contraints in the migration file 20161116202040-add-user-id-to-todos.js

```
module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Todos',
      'userId', {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Users',
          key: 'id'}})},
```

The models/user.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Todo);}}});
  return User;};
```

the models/todo.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Todo = sequelize.define('Todo', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },{  
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Todo.belongsTo(models.User); }}});
  return Todo;};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequelize has a way to associate the related models via the model name.

So for example

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', { ... });
var Todo = sequelize.define('todo', { ... });

Todo.belongsTo(User);

// Will create/use `userId` in Todo table
```

But in your case where you have the table name as capitals :

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', { ... });
var Todo = sequelize.define('Todo', { ... });

Todo.belongsTo(User);

// Will create/use `UserId` in Todo table
```

So in your case you can either rename `userId` to `UserId` or specify explicitly the foreignKey like

```
Todo.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: "userId" });
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. It seems to me that you'd also have to add foreignKey: "userId" to the User.hasMany call right?